# Display images in QT4 app over VNC and SSH

Tags: c++, qt4, vnc

I am trying to run my QT Application over VNC, and I am seeing some differences.

My images are loaded into QImage items, and are RGB images. I want to only work on the grayscale images, so I have attempted to create a grayscale image like so:

```
    QRgb col;
     int gray;
     for (int i = 0; i < imwidth; ++i)
     {
           for (int j = 0; j < imheight; ++j)
           {
                col = chip.pixel(i, j);
                gray = qGray(col);
                chip.setPixel(i, j, qRgb(gray, gray, gray));
            }
     }
```

where chip is my QImage

Then to get the raw data of chip, I use the following:

```
 int chipDataLength = chip.bytesPerLine();

     qDebug("Chip Width: %i", imwidth);
     qDebug("Chip height: %i", imheight);
     qDebug("Bytes per line : %i",chipDataLength);
     int bpp = chipDataLength/imwidth;

     qDebug("Size uchar: %i", sizeof(unsigned char) );
     qDebug("Size of qRgb: %i", sizeof(qRgb(1,1,1)));
     unsigned char * tempData = (unsigned char *)malloc(imheight*chipDataLength*sizeof(unsigned char));

     unsigned char * oneBandData = (unsigned char *)malloc(imheight*imwidth*sizeof(unsigned char));

     tempData = chip.bits();

     for (int i = 0; i < imheight; i++)
     {
           for (int j = 0; j < imwidth; j++)
           {
               oneBandData[i*imwidth+j] = tempData[i*chipDataLength + j*bpp];
           }
     }
```

When I run this code over SSH connection (or just sitting at the server), the code works fine, and oneBandData has the expected values in it. When I try to run it over VNC, oneBandData is not correct!

I have tried to use the options -qgraphicssystem raster, but it still gives me a distored image.

Also, that bpp variable was added, because chipDataLength was coming out to be 4*imwidth on SSH, and 2*imwidth on VNC. Why is this different? What can I do to make this code work both ways?

Comment: So I left he code as-is, and started VNC server with 24 bit color depth, and that takes care of the problem. I guess because I was using a QImage that was coming out of my view, QT must upgrade or downgrade the color depth to the display, instead of leaving it at whatever the original file was at. Kind of annoying. Setting the color depth solves the problem. It would be nice to have a way to run this without worry about that though.